# I cannot build boost_regex code because of link erros

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I'm trying to use boost_regex on ubuntu 12.04 (gcc 4.8.2).

I've installed boost like this.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

And I've confirmed boost_regex libraries are installed on.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep regex
libboost_regex.a
libboost_regex.so
libboost_regex.so.1.54.0
```

Then, I've tried to build a regex program code. But I faced link errors. Then what should I add link libraries?

```
 #include <boost/regex.hpp>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 int main()
 {
   std::string line;
   boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

   while (std::cin)
   {
     std::getline(std::cin, line);
     boost::smatch matches;
     if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
       std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
   }
 }


$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o out test2.cc -lboost_regex  
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_52::Locale::~Locale()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_charType_52'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_52::Locale::Locale(icu_52::Locale const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_digit_52'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_52::Collator::createInstance(icu_52::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_52::Locale::Locale()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_charFromName_52'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_tolower_52'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_isspace_52'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_isblank_52'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

Package `libboost-dev-all` depends on (using `dpkg --status`):

```
libboost-dev
libboost-tools-dev
libboost-atomic-dev
libboost-chrono-dev
libboost-context-dev
libboost-coroutine-dev
libboost-date-time-dev
libboost-exception-dev
libboost-filesystem-dev
libboost-graph-dev
libboost-graph-parallel-dev
libboost-iostreams-dev
libboost-locale-dev
libboost-log-dev
libboost-math-dev
libboost-mpi-dev
libboost-mpi-python-dev
libboost-program-options-dev
libboost-python-dev
libboost-random-dev
libboost-regex-dev
libboost-serialization-dev
libboost-signals-dev
libboost-system-dev
libboost-test-dev
libboost-thread-dev
libboost-timer-dev
libboost-wave-dev
```

As you can see, e.g. `libboost-regex-dev` doesn't contain the libraries:

```
$ dpkg --listfiles libboost-regex-dev 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex-dev/changelog.gz
```

That's because `libboost-regex-dev` depends on `libboost-regex1.54-dev`:

```
$ dpkg --listfiles libboost-regex1.54-dev 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a
/usr/share/doc/libboost-regex1.54-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
```

Ah! But it requires ICU:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc265fb000)
libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007feb20dc0000)
libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007feb209b9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007feb2063d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007feb20426000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feb20208000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feb1fe43000)
libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007feb1e5d6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feb1e3d2000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feb1e0cc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feb21440000)
```

So, who provides that?

```
$ dpkg --search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52
libicu52:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52
```

There's your clue:

## solution

```
$ sudo apt-get install libicu52
```

Comment: sehe you always amaze :-) i followed similar steps on my gentoo box to get my boost happy.  in my case, i bumped my box without rebuilding boost, and boost wasn't finding libicu, because it was looking for v57 when i'd moved to v58.  rebuild boost, fixed.  thanks for another helpful answer.

Comment: Two years later, and I'm here again to find the solution.  One of these years I'll remember.  :-)

Comment: @moodboom I usually run into my own answers. I just think SO is a 
very large shared notepad :)

Answer (score 0):

I have put your code in test.cpp

and

I just tested compiling your code like this:

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_regex
```

I don’t have any error right now, it's working

of course I used this command before:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

tested under ubuntu 15.04